# Compiling model for two mongos with same db and collection name

Tags: mongodb, model, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose` to access two Mongo relpSets and the db name and the collection name are same for both relpSets.

The schemas, however are different.

I'm not able to compile models for those as according to the [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html):

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model
>   is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your
>   model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the
>   tanks collection in the database.

I'm getting a error :

```
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
```

Is there anyway to change this behaviour?
Or any other way to compile model?

Comment: If they have different sources and different schemas then they are by nature **not** the same model, nor should you name them that way. The reistration of the "ModelName" to mongoose **must** be unique. Perhaps you are confusing "ModelName" with "CollectionName", which is acutally an optional third argument in the constructor: `mongoose.model("ModelName",modelSchema,"AcutalCollectionNameToUse")`. The error means what it says, so don't use `User` twice. Use `User1` and `User2` or something more descriptive instead.